# RecyclerView cannot resove for appcompat-v7:23.0.0 and 22

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a new list using RecyclerView to convert my existing ListView but problem is I can't find why my app cannot import the RecyclerView. I've just updated my SDK and other tools so I can work with Marshmallow in the future so everything is updated.

What I have in my app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.recyclerview"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

and after adding this line on my layout xml I got the error saying *The following classes could not be found: -android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Downgrading my buildtools and targetSDK version is quite not a good option for me since I only have version 22 and 23 but in case I tried to downgrade my app compat version into 21 it result into this error:

*This support library should not use a lower version (21) than the targetSdkVersion (23)*

Does it mean that the RecyclerView is removed from app compat 23? or I missed something here?

Comment: The script seems correct. Did you try to run gradle clean?

Comment: yes, I've even clean the project many times but nothing happens. the list of external libraries listed as well doesn't seems to add the recyclerview and other support libraries I've tried to add.

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, I've tried to just create a new test project to test it using the same dependencies and it works. libraries are imported successfully but I'm not sure why the other project doesn't seems to download and import those libraries. I will try to find the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that something was messed out with my configuration which cause is still unknown. It may be on the IML file or other part but it appears that the libraries are not being imported from the source which is why even after I sync and clean the gradle project the libraries from external source remains the same and still builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a stupid question but it's the only thing I can imagine is happening

You said that you had downloaded Marshmallow API but have you downloaded the Android Support Library?

The RecyclerView is part of the support library, not the "normal" SDK

Comment: And I think it is also stupid to post your question as the answer but yes I updated both SDK and other tools that includes the support library. I will know the error on the gradle after building it if the problem is in gradle build. I hope next time you can make use of the comment section. :)